# Primefaces DataTable - rowSelectListener hiding CommandButton inside rows

Tags: java, datatable, primefaces

I have a PrimeFaces DataTable, where each row has a **save**, **delete** and another **commandButton**. The dataTable has `selectionMode="single"` and a `rowSelectListener`. When I am clicking on the command buttons, the `rowSelectListener` is fired, but the commandButton's action is not getting fired.

What to do? I need both to fire!

I cannot use `immediate="true"` since there are some form fields, outside the dataTable, which must be submitted. It works with `immediate="true"` added in the commandbutton.

Primafaces version: 2.2.1
JSF version: 2.0.3

Thank you in advance for any leads!

Code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:v="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/composite"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
    <h:form id="contractReasonAddFormId">
            <span class="error">
                <h:messages /> 
            </span>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellspacing="5" >
        <h:outputLabel class="label" value="#{resourceBundle.coAddReason_coStatus_label_Key}" />
        <h:outputText class="output" value="#{selectedContractService != null ? selectedContractService.COS_STATUS_DESC : contract.CO_STATUS_DESC}" />
        <h:outputLabel class="label" for="reasonId" value="#{resourceBundle.contractChangeStatus_NewReason_Key}:" />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="reasonId" value="#{bbNewStatusReason.selectedString}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{resourceBundle.contractChangeStatus_NewReason_Key} #{resourceBundle.valueIsRequired}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="- #{resourceBundle.contractChangeStatus_SelectReason_Key} -" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{bbNewStatusReason.list}" var="r" itemValue="#{r.REASON}" itemLabel="#{r.RS_DES}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <!-- some other form fields --->
    <h:panelGrid>
        <p:dataTable 
        id="currentStatusReasonTable" 
        value="${bbCurrentStatusReason.list}" 
        var="currStReason"
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{bbCurrentStatusReason.selectedItem}"
        rowSelectListener="#{contractAddReasonAction.selectReason}" onRowSelectUpdate="reasonValidityTimes"         
        >
            <p:column sortBy="#{currStReason.RS_DES}" headerText="#{resourceBundle.coAddReason_currStReason_label_Key}">
                <h:outputText value="#{currStReason.RS_DES}: "/>
            </p:column>
            <!-- Other columns -->
            <p:column headerText="#{resourceBundle.coAddReason_action_facet_Key}">
                <p:commandButton id="updateReasonId" action="dlgUpdate" image="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" title='#{resourceBundle["button.save"]}' disabled="#{selectedContractService != null ? currStReason.LEVEL == 'C' : false}" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bbCurrentStatusReason.selectedItem}" value="#{currStReason}" />
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton id="deleteReasonId" action="dlgDelete" image="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-minus" title='#{resourceBundle["button.delete"]}' disabled="#{selectedContractService != null ? currStReason.LEVEL == 'C' : false}" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bbCurrentStatusReason.selectedItem}" value="#{currStReason}" />
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:commandButton id="generateDeleteDocumentsId" action="generateDeleteDocuments" image="ui-icon" title='#{resourceBundle["button.generateDocumentsForDel"]}' immediate="true" rendered="#{showPrintDocument != null}" >
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bbCurrentStatusReason.selectedItem}" value="#{currStReason}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

    </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form> 
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem.  What I ended up using on the commandButton was event.stopPropagation() within the onclick attribute.  Here is my delete button.

```
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                             onclick="connDelConfirm.show(); event.stopPropagation();" 
                             actionListener="#{connectionController.setSelectedConnection(connection)}"
                             disabled="#{connection.deleted}"/>
```

The other action on the onclick attribute opens a confirm dialog for the delete action.  Since the propagation of the event was stopped.  I needed a way to still set the selected item to be deleted.  This was accomplished through the action listener.  I simply called the setSelectedItem method in the bean and passed it the 'var' attribute from the dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Use **component binding** for input component with `immediate="true"`.

You have to play between **input component** and **action component** using `immediate="true"`.

You need to reference [JSF Lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) effect of `immediate="true"`;

BeanOne.java

```
@ManagedBean(name="BeanOne")
@RequestScoped
public class BeanOne {
    private HtmlInputText inputText;

    public HtmlInputText getInputText() {
        return inputText;
    }

    public void setInputText(HtmlInputText inputText) {
        this.inputText = inputText;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("HtmlInputText ==>" + inputText.getValue());
    }
}
```

pageOne.xthml

```
<h:inputText binding="#{BeanOne.inputText}" immediate="true"/><br/>
<h:commandButton value="Show_1" action="#{BeanOne.show}" immediate="true"/>
<h:commandButton value="Show_2" action="#{BeanOne.show}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answers. However, the issue I was facing turned out to be something else completely. What was happening was that the action was getting trigerred all right, but there was a jsf element with 'required=true' - and this was throwing a validation error which was not showing up anywhere - not even in console. After updating (ajax) the error message display pane of the page layout, the error message was seen.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers. However, the root cause of the issue I was facing turned out to be something else completely.

What was happening was that the action was getting triggered all right, but there was a jsf element with 'required=true' - and this was throwing a validation error which was not showing up anywhere - not even in console. After updating (in the primaface command button, ajax - using 'update=' attribute) the error message displaying pane of the page layout, the error message was seen.

Thanking you,
Rajarshi Mukherjee